# Error "case" en expresión switch, 'mivariable' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

Necesito ayuda con un código que estoy haciendo, el código es para hacerles un programa de broma a unos amigos, el problema es que si ellos responden con 0 (no), yo quiero que les salga cierto texto, y luego el programa se termine, y no sé cómo hacerlo.

Entonces lo que hace el programa hasta ahora, es que cuando responden con 0 (no) les sale el texto que les tendría que salir, pero también les sale la pregunta que les tendría que salir si hubieran respondido con 1 (sí).

Éste es el código:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int a, b, c;

    cout<<"\n Responder con 1 (si) o 0 (no), por favor.";

    cout<<"\n¿Texto de la pregunta? ";cin>>a;

    switch (a){
        case 1: cout<<"Texto de la segunda pregunta";cin>>b;break;
        default: cout<<"Texto de la respuesta de broma"; break; 

    }
    switch (b){
        case 1: cout<<"Texto de la tercera pregunta";cin>>c; break;
        default: cout<<"Texto de la respuesta de broma"; break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por favor, no uses palabras malsonantes o vocabulario no apropiado en el sitio. Por favor, cambia el ejemplo de código para evitar ese tipo de frases/vocabulario.

Comment: Oh está bien, no me di cuenta, lo siento

Comment: @Drakzorg Cuando en el primer caso el usuario escribe el 0, la variable b no se inicializa y por lo tanto tendrás un error cuando el programa intente ver que hay dentro de la variable y vea que no está inicializada.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando tu programa pasa por el primer switch imprime tus mensajes, pero **no le das orden de que se detenga una vez que sale la respuesta de broma**. Entonces continua con el segundo switch y, como bien te comentan, te daría un error en el caso de haber elegido 0, porque b no estaría inicializado.

Puedes ordenar que el programa termine después del caso 0:

```
switch(a){
  case 1: cout << "Texto de la segunda pregunta"; cin >> b; break;
  default: cout << "Texto de la respuesta de broma"; return 0;
}
```

O puedes hacer que solo ejecute el segundo switch si la respuesta ha sido 1:

```
if(a==1){
  switch(b){
    case 1: cout << "Texto de la tercera pregunta"; cin >> c; break;
    default: cout << "Texto de la respuesta de broma"; break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me ayudó a terminar el programa. Suerte! ;D